# How to select in Postgresql difference between arrays in rows?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name text
  hobbies text[]
)
```

Data here gets inserted each day.

Now I have few rows. And I want to get the difference in hobbies arrays between rows.

E.g.

```
id |name | hobbies
1   Tom    [fishing, hunting, football]
2   James  [fishing, jogging]
3   Dave   [football, computer games]
```

I would compare 1st row with 2nd and 2nd row with 3rd (what's inside 1st row that's not in 2nd). So the result would be:

```
hobbies
[hunting, football, fishing, jogging]
```

I want to retrieve the array of differences inside the array.

Comment: Why do you have a single row as the result? Shouldn't you have one row per id? I.e (id_1, hobbies_1 - hobbies_2), (id_2, hobbies_2 - hobbies_3), …?

Comment: Per each entry I have 2000 elements, so I have put it in array. Hobbies just an example. These elements are all coordinates, so they always will be unique if not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a row per row diff, you can use a combination of `EXCEPT` and `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(diff_hobbies)
FROM
(
  SELECT id, unnest(hobbies)
  FROM people
  EXCEPT
  SELECT id, unnest(LEAD(hobbies) OVER (ORDER BY id))
  FROM people
) t(id, diff_hobbies)
GROUP BY id
;
┌────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ id │          array_agg          │
├────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ {football,hunting}          │
│  2 │ {jogging,fishing}           │
│  3 │ {football,"computer games"} │ 
└────┴─────────────────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This might work. Is it possible to use unnest in a way that it would not disassemble arrays inside that array?

Comment: Worked as expected. Thank you! @Marth